# How to prevent Crystal Reports from requesting credentials/parameters when setting the datasource directly?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I've used reflection to extract the sql query being used by a Crystal Report. I then use this extracted sql (very carefully) to fill a dataset, which IO then bind to my ReportDocument object via the SetDataSource method. All this goes smoothly, but whenever I'm trying to view or export my report, it requires that I provide my credentials / parameter values, which defeats the purpose of querying/binding my data manually.

Is there any way around having to provide credentials / parameters when my report data is being push into the report (i.e. can I get the report to not refresh istself from the database directly?) I've tried setting the "save with data" value, but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it can help:

```
ReportDocument cryReportDocument = .......;
cryReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("userName", "password");
cryReportDocument.SetParameterValue("parameterName", value);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryReportDocument;
```