# Logon failed, ADO Error Code: 0x

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, oledb

Up until a few weeks ago, my report successfully connected to the SQL Server. Now it shows this error:

```
---------------------------
Crystal Reports ActiveX Designer
---------------------------
Logon failed.
Details: ADO Error Code: 0x
Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
Description: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security error.
SQL State: 08001
Native Error: 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: This is SSL security error. Is your server configured to accept encrypted connection? Is your connection string configured correctly for enctyption?

Comment: I am not sure, whether IT personals did that, but the same connection string works through VB.code and also can be accessible through server-explorer in Visual Studio., but its unsuccessful through Crystal Report.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, simply update your crystal report with new sqlserver db. This error shows that your credential of sqlserver and report datasource's credentials are mismatch.

Ideally if you do this via your code, then always write this statement which dynamically access and set credentails

```
ReportDocument cryReportDocument = .......;
cryReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("userName", "password");
cryReportDocument.SetParameterValue("parameterName", value);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryReportDocument;
```

See the links

[How to prevent Crystal Reports from requesting credentials/parameters when setting the datasource directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759087/how-to-prevent-crystal-reports-from-requesting-credentials-parameters-when-setti)

[Dynamically set Crystal Report still asks for db login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236377/dynamically-set-crystal-report-still-asks-for-db-login)

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/696567/crystal-report-Runtime-Login-Prompt

This clearly tell you that something wrong with credentials. If this is in designer, it means your server definition may be change, so while connecting in update it required the exact db credential. Just recheck via **Database->Verify Database** and I think this resolved your issue.

[Why do I get "Database logon failed" in Crystal Reports when using .NET object as datasource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309533/why-do-i-get-database-logon-failed-in-crystal-reports-when-using-net-object-a)

Comment: Buddy, this is happening while updating a report in Report Designer, you need to connect with database to update attached table or stored procedure.

Comment: I did all, I can manage to logon with my local db using Set Database, or Verify butt couldnt be successful with that Db upon which the IT team have installed fewe security pathes and I started receiving the error only when I use to Verify Database.

Comment: are you able to login via SSMS? try this that will hint you about your security block(if any)

Comment: Yes. I can access through Server Explorer of VS even, but not through Verify Database of CR designer

Comment: try to access your local db and then another db via ssms and crystal report to understand security cause. if not understand , then check link - https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1650976 , https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf4e1679-1471-40d6-a0e2-58f69c88bd47/problem-in-crystal-report-when-i-click-verify-database?forum=vscrystalreports

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to crystal report.This is related to oledb provider, if your current provider is "Microsoft OLE DB provider for SQL Server" change it to "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server" or SQL server Native Client 11.0  and +.
Please create .UDL file and test.